# How to make the side drawer not shrink the main body, but come as an overlay on top of it

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend

So, I am using a similar code snippet as provided here(Material UI) :

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6xdsb?file=/demo.js)

When we click on the top left menu icon, it opens the side drawer which shrinks the main body, I wanted it to be able to come on top of the main body, sort of like overlay you can say. I tried changing the z-index but that didn't seem to work. Will really appreciate some help

Comment: From a pure css perspective, what you are looking for is altering the position attribute. `position:absolute/fixed` detaches the element it is set on from the html flow enabling it to overlay other parts.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked. I added `position:fixed` in the `drawerOpen` style defined there and the drawer opened as an overlay. One small issue that still seems to be there is, when closing the drawer, the main body still behaves like it got shrunk when we opened the drawer. Anything that could fix it?

Comment: Try check if the closing interacts with anything else but the `position:fixed` element. The fix element does certainly not induce the body movement

Answer (score 1):

The official way to do this is use default value of `variant` (`temporary`) of `Drawer` component. In your example, variant you use is `permanent`.
Of course you need to change CSS a bit to adapt yourself.

API document here: https://material-ui.com/api/drawer/
Offical demo here also: https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#temporary-drawer